# Check if javascript file was loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading the following javascript files from a CDN. Is there any way I can check if these have been loaded correctly and if not, load them from a local folder?

http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js
http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js

I know I can check the jquery file but not sure about the others. Any tips?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your HTML, you can do something like this:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

The example shown is loading jquery from Google CDN and falls back on a local copy of JQuery if that fails.

Credits to [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) for showing the trick

Comment: For ui and validate, do that same, checking for $.ui or $.validate

Comment: Thanks to both. Scottm - $.ui does the trick in checking if ui javascript is loaded but unfortunately $.validate does not. Any tips as how I check for the validate plugin?

Comment: Anyone have any idea regarding checking if the validate plugin is loaded?

Comment: I think you can check for existence of **jQuery.fn.myPlugin** & if it hasn't loaded from the external source, then fetch it from the local copy. So for your case it could be something like : <script>!window.jQuery.fn.validate && document.write('<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

Comment: Is there a quick an easy way to integrate into this https - so that the cdn will change its url to https if the web page is in https?

Comment: @Niall, Yes! You can use something like this :

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.4.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>

You can read more here:http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Answer (score 3):

[YepNope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) is a more robust solution for loading resources (like js files), checking whether they've been loaded or not, and then providing a fallback if necessary. This is just 1 feature among many provided by the library.

Comment: This resource link is broken... Can you please, update it?