# Javascript loaded check through jquery getscript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load a Javascript file on the click event instead of loading at the page load event, for performance reasons.
Is there anyway to know that particular if javascript is already loaded?

Right now I am maintaining a global variable to check the 'loaded' event

```
var javascriptLoaded=false

if (!javascriptLoaded)
        $.getScript('/scripts/test.js', function() {
            javascriptLoaded = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
            callSomeFunctionhere(); 
            }, 1000);                     
        });
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if javascript file was loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036203/check-if-javascript-file-was-loaded)

Comment: @Diodeus That question answers only the jquery as jquery has $ or Jquery object

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you want to do is use the success callback. A call back method which will only be called once the ajax request to load the script has successfully finished. For example this is equivalent:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/myscript.js",
dataType: "script",
success: function(){
  scriptLoaded = true;
  //do some more stuff now that the script is loaded
 }
failure: function(){
  scriptLoaded = false; 
 }

});
```

Comment: thanks though , i am already doing this if you look at my code

Comment: Ah, I see. Try using require.js http://requirejs.org/ or if you also want to add conditional loading you could use yepnope.js http://yepnopejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to check if a script has been loaded is to see if that script is callable:

```
if($.fn.foo == undefined) {
    $.getScript("/path/to/script/foo.js", function() {
        // success 
    });
}
```